"A coordinate transformation changes components, but not one-forms themselves"
I'm very puzzled by a statement made by Sean Carroll in his Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity textbook.
Discussing tensor densities at page 89, he says:
"But the functions appearing in $d^nx = dx^0 \wedge ... \wedge dx^{n-1}$ are the coordinate functions themselves, so when we change coordinates we replace the one-forms $dx^\mu$ with a new set $dx^{\mu'}$. You see the funny business-ordinarily a coordinate transformation changes components, but not one-forms themselves"
Here you find the assertion in context.
In what sense a coordinate transformation does not change one-forms? All I have read about coordinate transformation for contravariant tensors show that specifically "the $dx$s" get changed...

What does "change a 1-form" mean?

I imagine  that Carroll  means that if ${\boldsymbol\omega}$ is a $p$-form and $X_1,\ldots, X_p$ are vector fields, then
$$
{\boldsymbol \omega}(X_1,\ldots, X_p).
$$
is independent of any coordinate choice. On the other hand the basis 1-forms $dx^\mu$ clearly do depend on the choice of the coordinate functions $x^\mu$.

I think all he means is that coordinate transformations do not change the vector per se, but it's coordinates. A 1-form is of course also a vector in the space of linear maps, i.e. the dual space.
But since he is talking about the basis vectors, a change of basis obviously changes them.
